# Excel crashes when creating/generating a powerpoint on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to generate a Powerpoint from Excel with VBA. On Windows everything is working fine. I have very very simple code atm:

```
Sub pptTest()

    Dim PowPntApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PowPntPrsnt As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PowPntSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

    Set PowPntApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    PowPntApp.Visible = True
    PowPntApp.Activate

    Set PowPntPrsnt = PowPntApp.Presentations.Add

    Set PowPntSlide = _
    PowPntPrsnt.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)

End Sub
```

When I run this macro on my Macbook, it does open powerpoint with a new slide, but it completely crashes Excel to the point I have to force quit the application. Why is that?

Excel version: `16.61.1 (22052000)`

Macbook: `MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021) M1 Chip` (no clue if this is relevant)

**EDIT**

I've ran the code a couple of times. Sometimes it works, sometimes it only crashes Excel, sometimes it only crashes Powerpoint and sometimes it crashes both Excel AND Powerpoint. Very inconsistent. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? Which line causes the crash?

Comment: @JohnKorchok I have no clue. Since excel crashes completely and I have to force quit the application, I can't 'debug' the code or see on what line it crashes.

Comment: It sounds like you may not know how to step through code. Open your code in the VBE. Click on the left margin beside _Set PowPntApp = New PowerPoint.Application_. A reddish-brown line should appear over that line of code. Now run the Sub. The execution will halt at the brown line. Then click on the _Step Into_ key on the VBE toolbars. It will step through the code one line at a time and crash at the line causing the problem.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Thank you. It seems to crash at `Set PowPntPrsnt = powPntApp.Presentations.Add`.

Comment: This looks like a long-standing bug in Office for Mac that appears to have begun when Microsoft started sandboxing the apps so they could be sold on the Apple Store. About the best you can do is report it to Microsoft. Place the code on a worksheet or slide, then click on the "person with speech bubble" icon in the upper right corner of the program window. Choose _I don't like something_. Describe the problem, indicate the line that raises an error and include a screenshot to show the VBA. Submitting will send a report to the Mac programming team. They are unlikely to reply.

Comment: @JohnKorchok I was afraid that that would be the case. I will report. Thanks for looking into the problem with me.